# Is there a way to understand the order words appear in a string in R?

Tags: r, excel-formula

I have been given an excel spreadsheet that I am hoping to convert in to R as excel is problematic and the excel sheet is very manual and more labour intensive. I have tried to recreate the excel output below with the formulas (row 2 of the table) and outputs (row 3). Basically it has individual words or phrases and counts how many characters are in front of the word you are searching for and then in column C returns the lowest number of characters ie. the first to be written about.

| rows/columns | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client | Notes | Word List > | feeding | weight | growth | growth check |
| 2 | 001 | The client had weight taken, showed growth with good feeding | =MIN(D2:G2) | =IFERROR(LEN(LEFT($B2,FIND(D$1,$B2))),"") | =IFERROR(LEN(LEFT($B2,FIND(E$1,$B2))),"") | =IFERROR(LEN(LEFT($B2,FIND(F$1,$B2))),"") | =IFERROR(LEN(LEFT($B2,FIND(G$1,$B2))),"") |
| 3 | Output |  | 16 | 54 | 16 | 37 |  |

The data is over 20,000 clients and there is over 400 words and phrases in the list, so obviously going through each one individually and reading each note is impossible but I am hoping to be able to obtain an output like the excel one where I can say "out of this list of words the first word to be mentioned was X" so for the example above "weight" was written about first in the notes.

**EDIT** adding what the R input and output would ideally look like:

Word list:
feeding, weight, growth, growth check

Input file:

| Client | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | The client had weight taken, showed growth with good feeding |
| 002 | A growth check was conducted |
| 003 | Growth and weight taken |

Output file:

| Client | Notes | Word Priority1 | Word Priority2 | Word Priority3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | the client had weight taken, showed growth with good feeding | weight | growth | feeding |
| 002 | a growth check was conducted | growth check | NA | NA |
| 003 | growth and weight taken | growth | weight | NA |

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, for the words in columns D to G, search for a word, count the characters before [Excel's `LEFT()`] it and return the minimum. What if the word is not found? And do you have a list of search words or just one? Please give an example of a few (two or three) short phrases and a search word plus the expected output.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. There is a list of over 400 words/phrases which change every couple of months. In excel if the word is not found then the cell is just left blank.

Comment: Note that you will get false positives in the order words appear here. For example, if you are going to check `growth` before `growth check` you'll find it's both true in `This is a growth check`. If you even want to find just `growth` here, you'd need to make sure you search the two in the right order because I think the word priority here is `growth check` first. Also, initially I thought this could be a nice usecase for regex using word-boundaries, but then you mentioned a list of 400+ words. That would get very sluggish fast.

Comment: @JvdV its the word priority and the way R reads strings that I think is causing my issues. Excel is more manual and crashes a bit more but at least can handle the varying words and phrases it gets as its just asking for the number of characters before that word/phrase appears and then just finds the lowest character count

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

initial_df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~txt,
  001, "The client had weight taken, showed growth with good feeding",
  002, "A growth check was conducted",
  003, "Growth and weight taken"
)

phrases <- c(
  "feeding",
  "weight",
  "growth check",
  "growth"
)

(fin <- mutate(rowwise(initial_df),
  found_phrases_1 = list(map_int(
    phrases,
    ~ str_locate(str_to_lower(txt), .x)[1]
  ) |>
    set_names(phrases) |>
    na.omit() |>
    sort() |> names())
) |>
  unnest_longer(col = "found_phrases_1") |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_prefix = "Word Priority ",
    names_from = "rn",
    values_from = "found_phrases_1"
  ) |> ungroup())
```